# Serenity Screenplay use search context inside Target locator

Tags: selenium-webdriver, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I am using Serenity for automation tests. I used before the plain WebDriver and PageObject pattern.
I thought to switch to Serenity for the high API availability and Screenplay pattern.
I encountered a problem using the Screenplay pattern:

1. I use the Target class to located the element
2. I use the following line to ensure a given element is visible:

```
actor.attemptsTo(Ensure
                .that(target)
                .isDisplayed());
```

Question: Is there a way to pass the current PageObject or a WebElementFacade to the Target or where is used the Target. So I would like to avoid for searching the entire DOM. Also there can be cases multiple elements are present so it is required to limit the searching area in the DOM.

I achieved this thing with the WebDriver and PageObject pattern easily. I searched within the PageObject's WebElement. I used nested PageObjects in order to define a Page and reuse the common components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can seach relative to a target using element.inside("your locator").
Would that help?